# Referencing index to a method that's in html. Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

I'm trying to reference the "index" that's in `<tr v-for="(note, index) in noteList" v-bind:key="index"` to *shareToPublic(index)*. The *selectedID()* method selects the index and returns the current ID number. Afterwards, when I click the Share button it should take me to a page that shows the content that was selected from the ID.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-delete" @click="shareToPublic(index)">Share</button>    
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(note, index) in noteList"
        v-bind:key="index"
        v-if="note.workspace_id === currentWorkspace"
        @dblclick="getNote(note.id)"
        @click="selectedId(index)" >
        <td>{{ note.title }}</td>
        <button type="submit" @click="deletePage(note.id, index)">Delete</button>
      </tr>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts">
  @Componet
  export default class ValueHub extends Vue {
  
    private selectedId(index: number): number {
      return this.noteList[index].id
    }
  
    async shareToPublic(index: numbrer){
      const numberToString = this.selectedId(index).toString()
      await this.$router.push({name: 'PublicContent', params: {id: numberToString}});
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is not the typos or missing code for `nodeList` etc, create a variable called `selected` to store the selected `id` (not index):

```js
export default class ValueHub extends Vue {
  selected: number | null = null;  // Will contain the selected id
  ...
}
```

Set `selected` to the `id` in the `selectedId` handler:

```js
private selectedId(id: number) {
  this.selected = id;
}
```

Pass the id instead of the index in `@click`:

```html
@click="selectedId(note.id)"
```

Use `selected` for the `id` in the router push:

```js
async shareToPublic(){
  await this.$router.push({
    name: 'PublicContent',
    params: { id: this.selected }
  });
}
```